get response code and hide response body for Curl API get command
I have a curl command I'm running in a unix script
curl -X GET 'my endpoint that i've removed' \
    -H 'Accept: */*' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
    -d 'xml body i've hidden because it contains credentials'

This works find but the response body is huge (and not necessary for me to see for my purposes) how do I hide the response body and also display the response code (200, 500 etc)
I've tried different flags (-I, -w, -s) but they all seem to only work for post commands not get.

-I (uppercase i) should work fine for http(s) GET. This shows only the headers. If you want to get only the HTTP status, you could also use -i (or -I) and pipe the result through a head -n=1, as that is returned as first line of the response headers.
